# How to overcome embedded authentication prevention of Chrome?

Tags: security

In recent versions of the Chrome, embedded authentication has got forbidden so we can't find a way through how to handle these JS authentication popups programmatically.

We want to get a picture from a secured server.

Like:
**http://admin:123456@192.0.0.1**

Also, the img src of HTML elements didn't work. The server responded 401 not authorized info.

Someone has any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add an endpoint to your application which takes the user authentication information ( as in Basic Auth ) through the HTTP Header and then treats the request for the file resource as a GET call and writes back the resource in the response.

Comment: I have no direct interference to the server.

Comment: In which case you will have to modify the client side to pass the basic auth in the HTTP request when trying to retrieve the resource...

Comment: There is a HikVision server, a CCTV camera, the case is I want to get picture from the endpoint. By the way it is not basic but digest.